# finding the percentage of wild animals in a cage

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage

I have a sub -query that contains a cage number and type of an animal (wild or not), all other columns are irrelevant for the Question.

I need to show the percentage of wild animals in the cage, in the attached Screen-Shot you can see that there are 2 wild animals from a total of 4 animal in cage number 11.

Can't remember the best way to get the result , since we can't divide count() by count().

Any help will be much appreciated . 
Thank You.

Query code:

```
select *
from animal , cage
where animal.cno = cage.cno  and cage.cno  in(
       select distinct cno
       from  animal  
       where   animal.cno = all
              (select cno
              from animal 
              where   type <> all
                      (select type
                       from animal
                        where type not in ('wolf' , 'sheep',  'Capricorn', 'tiger') )));
```

Table format:

```
create table cage 
(cno int primary key, wild boolean, size int,
check (size<=10000));

create table animal
 (aid int, cno int, type varchar(15), wild boolean,
 primary key(aid), 
 foreign key (cno) references cage
    on update cascade
    on delete set null);
```

Insertion code:

```
insert into cage
values (10,TRUE,1000),
       (11,TRUE,7500),
       (12,FALSE,700),
       (13,FALSE,200);

insert into animal
values(100,10,'monkey',TRUE),
      (110,11,'Sheep',FALSE),
      (120,11,'wolf',TRUE),
      (130,10,'bear',TRUE),
      (140,12,'frog',FALSE),
      (145,10,'dingo',FALSE),
      (160,11, 'Capicorn',FALSE),
      (155,11,'Tiger',TRUE),
      (150,13,'deer',FALSE);
```

Screen shot :

[image]

Screen shot link :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m14t6o137q5z4gn/Screenshot%202014-11-20%2010.59.16.png?dl=0

Comment: "*since we can't divide count() by count()*" - why not? And please post the table structure and sample data as text (preferably as `create table` and `insert` statements). We can't copy and past the SQL from a screenshot. Or better: create a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I cannot insert the data cause of the check constraint. You have `check (size <= 1000)`, but trying to insert 7500

Comment: My bad it's need to be 10,000. fixed

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select t.cno,
       total_count, 
       wild_animal_count,
       case 
         when wild_animal_count is null then 0
         else wild_animal_count::numeric / total_count::numeric
       end as percentage
from (
   select c.cno, 
          count(*) as total_count, 
          sum(case when a.wild then 1 end) as wild_animal_count
   from animal a
     join cage c on a.cno = c.cno
   group by c.cno
) t
order by t.cno;
```

The inner query counts all animals in a cage and the number for wild animals in a cage. 
The outer query then simply divides those numbers. The cast to numeric (the `::numeric` thing) is necessary because otherwise everything would be calculated as an integer (and thus the result of the division would be rounded).

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/12989/3

Note that I replaced your outdated (and fragile) implicit joins in the `where` clause with an explicit `JOIN` clause in the `from` part. You should really get used to that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the replay but couldn't quite understand how i merge this with my Query. and what is the meaning of animal a and cage c , you can probably see that i'm new to sql.  thanks

Comment: That is using aliases in SQL. It makes queries more concise and in fact more readable. Check this page for more info about that: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp